# SQL: Convert GMT in seconds to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with two columns of GMT time in seconds, and offset in minutes like this:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 StartTime, OffSet FROM MyTable;
  1247242537  -420 -- as example
```

What SQL function I can use to convert it to a datetime in yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss as TimeStamp? The SQL I am using is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, assuming you Epoch date is 1/1/1970 (usually for GMT seconds, but you will need to confirm)

```
select dateAdd(ss,1247242537+(-420*60),'1/1/1970') 
 == >  2009-07-10 09:15:37.000
```

For you code, use

```
select DATEADD(ss,StartTime+(Offset*60),'1/1/1970') as TheTime FROM myTable
```

Be sure you find some test cases to make sure the Epoch date is as expected.   Basically, the GMT time is number of seconds past 1/1/1970 12:00am, so DateAdd handles that part.   The offset is the number of minutes different from GMT, so multiply that by 60 to get seconds and adjust your value to DateAdd accordingly